# WHY DOES neo4j EXPLAIN show thousands of rows with a filter DISTINCT node that is unique?

Tags: neo4j

This does not happen all the time, but with the exact same dbase (and perhaps different node search), my EXPLAIN keeps showing thousands of rows where I would just expect one. Am I missing something?

eg:

```
EXPLAIN MATCH (node:Label) 
WHERE node.UniqueID=1 
WITH DISTINCT node  
RETURN node
```

[image: Explain Flow]

There are 11000 record with that label, and that shows a correct start.
But then the filter narrows down to 1,105 which makes no sense.
And the DISTINCT narrows down to 1,105 which also makes no sense.

When I run the query, I just get my one unique node. When I run the explain, it shows 1105 rows as result. Why the discrepency? I've noticed when this happens that everything downstream stalls so I think Query is doing more work than it needs to but I'm not sure why.  I'd be most grateful for pointers to a resource that explains this better.

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

These are estimated rows calculated before query execution, it does not represent actual rows from the execution (you would use PROFILE to see that).

The estimated rows are exactly that, estimates by considering what is known from the graph via statistics and data from the counts store.

Since these are calculated before execution, the planner has no idea about the specificity of the property being used for lookup.

If you really have a unique ID, then you should be creating a unique constraint on it, that way the planner will be able to understand that and produce a more useful estimate. It will also be able to leverage the index (which comes with a unique constraint) to improve the lookup speed.

Also with such a change, you would no longer need to use DISTINCT since the unique index lookup would guarantee it.

Comment: Thanks this explains it. I did not understand that EXPLAIN is an estimate (as opposed to PROFILE). You're right - profile does return just 1 row.

Comment: Does EXPLAIN have a hard time estimating apoc procedures? I'm using apoc.refactor.mergeNodes to merge two unique nodes, and from those two unique nodes I get 10,000 estimated rows instead of 1. (The query crashes so I can't profile it).

Comment: The planner won't be able to get any relevant data from a procedure call, so don't rely on db hits or estimated rows from procedure call operators to be accurate or useful.

Comment: The big takeaway here is that you don't need to worry much about estimated rows. The planner is often making ballpark estimates extrapolated from what it knows, but the estimated rows are really only useful for figuring out how to plan the query, not so useful for query tuning. Actual rows from PROFILE are very useful, in contrast. If you're having trouble with a query, either create another question or ask on our community forums.